# How can I show custom image in UITableView accessory view in Objective-C?

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, accessoryview

I am doing a project in Objective-C. My problem is now,

Suppose I have a UITableView I want when I select a row it can show image with current position of user and remaining rows no need to show the same image.

I tried with lot of examples but no use.

can anyone help me? please...

Comment: Question is vague - where do you want to show the arrow? If user selects a row, that is where he is in the tableview. Do you want to show a checkmark for the selected row?

Comment: in the place of checkmark i want right arrow indicator

Answer (score 0):

Upon row selection, you should grab a cell and create your custom accessory view with that cell:

```
UITableViewCell * cell = [self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
BOOL bSelected = YES; 
[self createAccessoryView:cell :bSelected];
```

Note however that `bSelected` bool above should ideally come from your model array, the array that holds your table view objects. Upon row selection, it will simply negate its value, such as:

```
bSelected = !bSelected;
```

Your `createAccessoryView` would look something like this:

```
- (void) createAccessoryView : (UITableViewCell *) cell :(BOOL)bSelected
{
    UIImage * image = bSelected ? [UIImage imageNamed:@"check"] : [UIImage imageNamed:@"uncheck"];
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;

    UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    CGRect frame = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 40, 40);
    button.frame = frame;
    [button setBackgroundImage:image forState:UIControlStateNormal];

//Uncomment below line if necessary
//[button addTarget:self action:@selector(accessoryButtonTapped:event:)  forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    button.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    cell.accessoryView = button;
}
```

Off course, substitute your own image names above.

If you need more functionality in table view with some ready-made customisations (search, select, delete), take a look at [this ViewController](https://github.com/vividcode/TableSearchViewController/tree/master/Objective%20C) developed by me on github.

Comment: thanks for reply. it's not working properly.what i want is if i click on the row 1 it  should be show image .and remaining cells are hide the same image

Comment: when i click on first row image showing after click on second row first row of image not hiding it's remains same

Comment: You could get further rows after selected indexpath, using this: 
`NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:rowIndex inSection:sectionIndex];` Then apply same function `createAccessoryView` with `bSelected = false`.

Answer (score 0):

First of all place an image view in your cell, and put it as imgView.hidden  = YES. When you select the cell, the image view of that cell to be unhide.

//Sample Code

IndexSelected = 99999 // In viewdidload

-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

IndexSelected = indexpath.row;

[tbl reloaddata];

}

-(nonnull UITableViewCell *)tableView:(nonnull UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(nonnull NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

if(IndexSelected == indexpath.row){

cell.imgView.hidden = NO;

}

Comment: ya i already placed it and also hidden image . but how to show image when select a perticuler row.can you provide some code?.because i new to ObjectiveC

Comment: Ok, first you create an NSInteger globally (Example 'IndeXSelected') and declared it as  zero in ViewDidLoad. When you select a cell, the indexpath of that cell stored it into your variable, and reload the tableview. at cellforrowatindexpath check the indexpath with your varible, if it equals unhide the imageview.

Comment: provide me some code i don't understand what you saying